# How do I load and display the contents of an external json file into my python kivy app

Tags: python, json, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to create a kivy app where, in the first screen the user can select a json configuration file using FileChooserIconView. There is an empty label that would display the contents of the json file by turning its contents into a python dictionary. The following is my approach but I keep getting an error for the on_submit attribute of FileChooserIconViewer.

The error I am getting is on `self.load_json_file`  and it says:

```
  Type "(file_chooser: Unknown, selection: Unknown) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(selected: Unknown, touch: Unknown | None = None) -> None"
    Parameter name mismatch: "selected" versus "file_chooser"
    Parameter name mismatch: "touch" versus "selection"
    Parameter "selection" is missing default
```

This is my main.py

```py
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import json
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView, FileChooser, FileChooserIconView
from plyer import filechooser 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



class TestWindow(Screen):
    def selected(self, filename):
        try:
            with open("data.json") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                self.json_text = str(data)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.json_text = "Error: File not found"
    def show_file_chooser(self):
        file_chooser = FileChooserIconView()
        file_chooser.filters = ["*.json"]
        file_chooser.path = '.'
        file_chooser.on_submit = self.load_json_file  
        popup = Popup(title= 'Select config json', content = file_chooser, size_hint=(0.8, 0.8))
        popup.open()
        
    def load_json_file(self, file_chooser, selection):
        if selection: 
            file_path = selection[0]
            with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
                json_dict = json.load(file)
                self.ids.json_label.text = str(json_dict) 

class WelcomeWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("Cluster.kv")

class ClusterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return kv
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ClusterApp().run()
```

this is my Cluster.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    TestWindow
    WelcomeWindow
    

<TestWindow>
    name: "test"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button: 
            text: "select json config"
            on_release: root.show_file_chooser()
        Label:
            id: json_content
            text: ""

<WelcomeWindow>:
    name: "welcome"

    BoxLayout :
        orientation : "vertical"
        spacing: dp(50)
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.5}

        Button:
            text: "start clustering"

        Button: 
            text : "Settings"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "settings"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

someone please suggest a method to do this. I am fairly new to kivy and there aren't enough resources online that talk about dealing with json files in kivy. Some resources regarding the same would be great too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature for the `load_json_file()` method is incorrect. Try changing:

```
def load_json_file(self, file_chooser, selection):
```

to:

```
def load_json_file(self, selection, touch):
```